# Learning Ruby on Rails "RSpec"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following learn by example ruby book by michael hart, the book tells you to do bundle install and then generate the rspec:install.
I am running 3.0.4 rails and 1.9.2 ruby.
I get the answer cannot find generator rspec install.
Could anybody please enlighten me as to where the rspec should be.

Thank you

Comment: Did you add: gem "rspec-rails", inside your Gemfile?

Comment: Make sure you add "rspec-rails" to your Gemfile too.  Update your question with your Gemfile, the exact command you use to install rspec, and copy-paste the error.  Harder to help you without some more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up the Gemfile of your rails project and write :

```
gem "rspec-rails"
```

Then execute bundle install. Rspec resides in folder spec/ of your rails project.

Comment: Also, make sure the above is in the development group as well as test group or the generator will not be available.